# For each LOOP through JSON.Stringify EXIF data of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a image where once i click on it it is displayed bigger with EXIF data next to it . 
I am taking the EXIF data with JSON.strigify and after that i need to display whatever it is in that string to be added to the `<span>` tag with `id='makeAndModel'` in my HTML.

I want to do it with for each arrow function , but i am not sure how exactly .

```
   `<div id="imageContainer"></div>
      <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img class="modal-content" id="current">
        <pre>Make and model: <span id="makeAndModel"></span></pre>
    </div>`

   <--Taking the src attribute and creating the images-->
    let $modal = $('.modal')
    let $img = $("#imageContainer img");
      $img.click(function(){
        $('.modal-content').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
        $modal.css('display', 'block')

      <--EXIF data-->
       var imgCurrent = document.getElementById('current');
       EXIF.getData(imgCurrent,function(){
         let result = $('#makeAndModel')
         let make= JSON.stringify(EXIF.getAllTags(this));


    });

    let $makeAndModel = $('#makeAndModel');
    $makeAndModel.text(`${make}`)
  })
```

`

currently in the console the output of `let make` is object
`let make = {
    "Orientation":1,
    "YCbCrPositioning":1,
    "XResolution":72,
    "YResolution":72,
    "ResolutionUnit":2,
    "Make":"samsung",
    "Model":"SM-G965F",
    "Software":"G965FXXU2CSB9",
    "DateTime":"2019:03:18 18:29:28",
    "ExifIFDPointer":213,
    "GPSInfoIFDPointer":833,
    "ExposureTime":0.02,
    "FNumber":2.4,
    "ExposureProgram":"Normal program"
    ,"ISOSpeedRatings":160,
    "ExifVersion":"0220",
    "DateTimeOriginal":"2019:03:18 18:29:28",
    "DateTimeDigitized":"2019:03:18 18:29:28",
}`

Expected output should look like 
`Make and Model : 
Orientation:1, 
YCbCrPositioning:1, 
XResolution:72, 
YResolution:72,`

and so on  like when you click in the Properties->Details tab of an image

Comment: `JSON.stringify` returns a **String** - which has no `forEach` method - frankly I can't see what you're trying to achieve using JSON stringify - perhaps you just want `let make= EXIF.getAllTags(this);` - since that has a good chance of being an Array

Comment: also not sure what you think `$('#makeAndModel'+ '')` does ... but it doesn't do it

Comment: `let make= EXIF.getAllTags(this)` return  `[object Object]`  .  The `$('#makeAndModel'+ '')` is a mistake ,Yes , i have removed the whole  `make.forEach(element => {
          $('#makeAndModel'+ '') `

Comment: `[object Object]` does it? How do you know? Anyway ... `JSON.stringify` is how you create JSON string ... JSON.parse is how you create a plain ol' javascript object from a JSON string ... what exactly does `EXIF.getAllTags(this)` return?

Comment: Right, so `make` is an OBJECT, not an ARRAY ... only ARRAY has `forEach` - you could use `Object.entries(make).forEach(([key, value]) => ....)`

Comment: I will try now . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work

```
let $modal = $('.modal')
let $img = $("#imageContainer img");
$img.click(function() {
  $('.modal-content').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
  $modal.css('display', 'block')
  var imgCurrent = document.getElementById('current');
  EXIF.getData(imgCurrent, function() {
    let result = $('#makeAndModel')
    let make = EXIF.getAllTags(this);
    let props = Object.entries(make).map(([property, value]) => {
      return `${property}: ${value}`;
    });
    result.text(props.join('\n'));
  });
})
```